# When parsing JSON with Aeson, why is Maybe treated differently when it's in a type parameter?

Tags: haskell, aeson

Suppose we have some data classes

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, DuplicateRecordFields #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8
import GHC.Generics

data Foo a = Foo { payload :: a }
    deriving (Show, Generic)

instance ToJSON a => ToJSON (Foo a)
instance FromJSON a => FromJSON (Foo a)

data Bar a = Bar { payload :: Maybe a }
    deriving (Show, Generic)

instance ToJSON a => ToJSON (Bar a)
instance FromJSON a => FromJSON (Bar a)
```

Then we try to decode as following:

```
*Main > decode $ pack "{}" :: Maybe (Bar String)
Just (Foo {payload = Nothing})
*Main > decode $ pack "{}" :: Maybe (Foo (Maybe String))
Nothing
```

So why can't we decode JSON in the last try? The data classes seem to be the same, and they both work the same way with `toJSON`:

```
*Main > toJSON $ Foo (Nothing :: Maybe String)
Object (fromList [("payload",Null)])
*Main > toJSON $ Bar (Nothing :: Maybe String)
Object (fromList [("payload",Null)])
```

Comment: Have you compared against the JSON that is generated by `toJSON`? It's most likely expecting a different data format than you're anticipating.

Comment: It's expecting an explicit null.  Why it's expecting that in this case could be determined by `-ddump-deriv` and comparing the Generic instances of each type and if needed looking at the Generic JSON decoding in Aeson.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson That doesn't seem to explain the difference though. Both `Foo (Maybe String)` and `Bar String` contain a `Maybe String`. Both of them output a null payload when they encode. But only `Foo` requires a null payload when it decodes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Updated:* with a simple solution at the bottom.

This is confusing, but it's working more or less as designed.  You could try submitting it as an `aeson` issue, but I suspect it will be closed as "won't fix".

What's happening is that the generic instance generated for `FromJSON (Bar a)` is equivalent to:

```
instance FromJSON a => FromJSON (Bar a) where
  parseJSON = withObject "Bar" $ \v -> Bar
    <$> v .:? "payload"
```

Note the use of the `(.:?)` operator generated because of the `Maybe a` field in `Bar`.  In a structure with a mixture of `Maybe` and non-`Maybe` fields, there would be a corresponding mixture of `(.:?)` and `(.:)` operators.

Note that this instance is generated once and for all for every possible `a`.  The reason it's polymorphic is that the `(.:?)` implementation can dispatch to the `parseJSON` method in the `FromJSON a` dictionary supplied by the instance constraint.  Also note that the only reason we can use `(.:?)` is that it's known at compile time that for all possible types `a`, the field `payload` in the `Bar` object has type `Maybe a` and so use of the `(.:?)` operator will typecheck.

Now, consider the instance generated for `FromJSON (Foo a)`.  This will be equivalent to:

```
instance FromJSON a => FromJSON (Foo a) where
  parseJSON = withObject "Foo" $ \v -> Foo
    <$> v .: "payload"
```

It's exactly analogous to the `Bar a` instance above, except it uses the `(.:)` operator.  Again, it has a single implementation at compile time that works for every possible `a` by dispatching to `parseJSON` in the `FromJSON a` dictionary.  There's no way that this instance can use the `(.:?)` operator, since general `a` and `Maybe t` can't unify, and there's no way that it can somehow "inspect" the type `a`, whether at compile time or runtime, to see if it's a `Maybe`, for much the same reason that you can't write a total polymorphic function with type `a -> a` that's anything other than the identity.

Therefore, this `Foo a` instance can't make the `payload` field optional!  Instead, it has to treat `payload` as mandatory and -- when used to parse a `Foo (Maybe String)` -- dispatch to a `FromJSON t => FromJSON (Maybe t)` instance (which allows `null` but otherwise dispatches to the `FromJSON String` instance).

Now, why does it seemingly work fine for `ToJSON`?  Well, the instances for both `ToJSON (Foo a)` and `ToJSON (Bar a)` generate the same sort of (monomorphic) `Value` representation:

```
> toJSON (Foo (Nothing :: Maybe String))
Object (fromList [("payload",Null)])
> toJSON (Bar (Nothing :: Maybe String))
Object (fromList [("payload",Null)])
```

and the removal of null fields takes place uniformly when this value is encoded to JSON.

This leads to an unfortunate asymmetry in the `FromJSON` and `ToJSON` instances, but that's what's going on.

And I just realized I forgot to share the simple solution for fixing it.  Just define two generic instances for `Foo`, one overlapping instance to handle `Maybes` and the other for other types:

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} FromJSON a => FromJSON (Foo (Maybe a))
instance FromJSON a => FromJSON (Foo a)
```